# Confirmation delete window - deleting record when click delete or cancel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, dom-events, confirm

I have a Javascript file that contains the function for calling the confirmation delete window, the code used is similar to the following:

```
function Delete() 
{
    confirm('Delete this user');
    
}
```

I have a gridview with a template field that can delete a row in the gridview, this is a snippet of what I have:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amend" ShowHeader="false">
               <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:LinkButton ID="btnedit" runat="server" 
            CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" ></asp:LinkButton>
               </ItemTemplate>
               <EditItemTemplate>
                   <asp:LinkButton ID="btnamend" runat="server" 
            CommandName="Amend" Text="Amend" ></asp:LinkButton>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="btndelete" runat="server" 
            CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return Delete() "></asp:LinkButton>
               </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Within the aspx.vb page I have code to do the deletion of the record (this works fine), I have this code within the gridview property `OnRowDeleting="RowDeleting1"`

```
Protected Sub RowDeleting1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewDeleteEventArgs)
' code to do the deletion
```

When the confirmation of the delete appears (options are to delete or cancel), the deletion occurs when I click delete or cancel. Ideally I only want the deletion to occur when I click delete and just stay on the page when I click cancel, would anyone be able to advise what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `confirm('Delete this user');` with `return confirm('Delete this user');`

Comment: didnt realise it would be as simple as that :S thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ajax Confirm Button Extender](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/ConfirmButton/ConfirmButton.aspx), with some modification to your code.

ex:

```
 <cc1:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="btn_Delete_ConfirmButtonExtender" runat="server" ConfirmText="Delete this user?"
             Enabled="True" TargetControlID="btn_Delete">
 </cc1:ConfirmButtonExtender>
```